# ColorDrawable wont accept my integer resource

Tags: android, eclipse

I found a nice light blue color with a cool hex value: #abcdef
I am changing the action bar color using:

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xffabcdef));
```

But when I try to put that value in my integer resource:

```
  <integer name="_light_blue">0xffabcdef</integer>
```

The color becomes grey. The reason is:

```
    int i1 = 0xffabcdef;
    int i2 = R.integer._light_blue;
```

Value i1=-5517841 and value i2=2131099651.

Any fix ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setting `i2` to the resource id of that integer. Instead fetch the actual value:

```
int i =  0xffabcdef;
int i2 = getResources().getInteger(R.integer._light_blue);
Log.e("", i + " " + i2);
```

---

However here, it would be more precise to use a color resource (`res/values/colors.xml`):

```
<resources>
    <color name="_light_blue">#ffabcdef</color>
</resources>
```

And then use the color:

```
int myBlue = getResources().getColor(R.color._light_blue);
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(myBlue));
```